# Javascript remove function not working with name selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append input box with different names to DOM using jQuery by an add button and remove the last input box created using another remove button. But it seems `remove` function is not working. Console is giving value in `remove`.

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  set = 5;
  $('#show4').click(function() {

    $('#form4').append('<br/>Friends name<input type="text" name="namex' + set + '" />Friends msg<textarea rows="4" cols="50"  name="msg' + set + '" />');

    set = set + 1;
    console.log(set)

  });

  $('#show5').click(function() {
    console.log(set - 1)


    $('input[name=namex]' + set - 1).remove();
    $('input[name=msg]' + set - 1).remove();
    set = set - 1;

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show4">Add more friends</button>
<button id="show5">Remove friends</button>
<span id="form4"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

`'input[name=namex]'+set-1` evaluates as `NaN` because JS will try to append `set` as a string, and then substract 1 from a string, which results in NaN which means *Not a Number*.

Try `'input[name=namex'+(set-1) + ']'`

**UPDATE**

Here's the updated snippet. Made it a tad simpler with wrapping into a div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var set = 5;
  $('#show4').click(function() {

    $('#form4').append('<div id="friend' + set + '"><br/>Friends name<input type="text" name="namex' + set + '" />Friends msg<textarea rows="4" cols="50"  name="msg' + set + '" /></div>');

    set = set + 1;
    console.log(set)

  });

  $('#show5').click(function() {
    console.log(set - 1)

   set = set - 1;
    $('#friend' + set).remove();
    

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show4">Add more friends</button>
<button id="show5">Remove friends</button>
<span id="form4"></span>
```

Comment: @DeepakGupta I updated the answer. You closed the square bracket too early. Try this please